# Как раскрыть окно на все экраны - не 1

Tags: wpf

Как растянуть окно на все экраны ? Не на 1, а на все существующие.

Или как достигнуть эффект как при использовании "Ножницы" в Windows - когда затемняются все мониторы - явно же там окно ?.

**UPD**

Один из вариантов которых пока нашёл - это рассчитывать высоту и ширину + использование стартовой позиции.